# Selenium FluentWait wait before starting to poll

Tags: selenium, webdriver, wait

I'm using Selenium WebDriver to get some content from a site that dynamically loads it using Ajax. I created a custom Wait class to check for a condition on the page to make sure that the page has loaded before continuing. I used FluentWait to set the polling interval to 2 and timeout to 10. However, I noticed that it checks for the first time at time increment 0, then waits 2 seconds if the condition was false, then checks again, etc.

Since the page takes *some* time to load, it always is false at the first check, but usually is true at the second. Is there any way to make Wait wait the 2 seconds *before* checking for the first time? I.e. check at times 2,4,and 6, if necessary, rather than at 0,2,4,and 6?

Thanks,
 bsg

**EDIT**
I've been asked to mention *why* I want this behavior - after all, I'm using the Wait the way it's meant to be used. The benefit I get from it returning true the first time is the following: WebDriver apparently opens a new socket every time it issues a command to the browser. For whatever reason, these sockets don't always get closed after the call executes. When executing a large number of calls in a short time (for instance, when  repeatedly checking for a condition, which is what Wait does), it is possible to run out of virtual sockets, and the driver crashes. (The lack of enough virtual sockets seems to be a known issue on Windows 7, but I can't modify my system.)

The fewer calls to the driver I issue in a short period of time, the less likely it is to overrun the number of available sockets. I have observed that the first check *never* returns true, and therefore it's just opening a socket for no reason, making the program more likely to crash. That's why I want to wait. I hope this explanation is helpful for someone searching for information as to why they keep getting SocketExceptions in WebDriver.

Comment: You should mention what advantage you would have by first check returning true.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you need to bother with this - you are using the `wait` for what's it's intended for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious answer would be to just insert a `time.sleep(2)` (or similar method) before your first check. Would that work for what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes, this was the obvious answer. I wanted to see if there was a way to incorporate the desired functionality into the Wait itself, because I didn't really want to play around with the thread timing too much, but it seems that it's not possible. Thanks.